# Uploading a Image Works on some devices but returns Stream FixedLengthSource .inputStream()

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, okhttp

I am developing an android application that uploads an image to a specified directory using PHP and okhttp .  Well , the frontend and backend work fine on my personal device , but it crashes on non-Samsung devices.

When I dug into the problem I found out that the server returns :

com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource@17768aa).inputStream()
on the non-Samsung devices.

The Java Code of the file Upload is as Follows :

```
public class UploadGalleryStoryPost {
    private Context context;
    private String fileName = "", User_Id = "",Type="";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private String count = "";
    private String fileCount = "";

    public UploadGalleryStoryPost(String fileName, Context context, String User_Id, String Type, String count, String fileCount) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.context = context;
        this.User_Id = User_Id;
        this.Type = Type;
        this.count = count;
        this.fileCount = fileCount;
        new UploadingGalleryPost().execute();

    }

    private class UploadingGalleryPost extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize =1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile_profile = new File(fileName);
        private String upLoadServerUri = APP_SERVER_URL+"AddAStory.php";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try{
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    int count1 = Integer.parseInt(count);
                    int fileCount1 = Integer.parseInt(fileCount);
                    Log.e("value", " "+ String.valueOf(count1-1)+" "+fileCount1);
                    if((fileCount1-1) == count1) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.myDialog);
                        builder1.setCancelable(false);
                        builder1.setTitle("Alert!");
                        builder1.setMessage("Uploaded successfully.");
                        builder1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                Intent i = new Intent(context, DashBoard.class);
                                context.startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog1 = builder1.create();
                        dialog1.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(context, fileName+" has been uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("UploadtoserverException", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream_profile = new FileInputStream(sourceFile_profile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
//                conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Attachment", fileName);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Attachment\";filename=\""+fileName+"\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream_profile.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream_profile.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream_profile.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream_profile.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);



                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"User_Id\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(User_Id);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Type\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(Type);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                conn.getErrorStream();

                Log.e("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode+" "+ conn.getErrorStream());

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream_profile.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.e("UploadtoserverException", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The php code is :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+24 hours'));
$day = date("l");
$response = array();
include 'db_connect.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $User_Id = $_POST['User_Id'];
    $Story_Content = $_POST['Story_Content'];
    $B_Id = $_POST['B_Id'];
    $Type = $_POST['Type'];

    if($Type == 'BGTXT'){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Story_Common(User_Id,Timestamp_Start,Status, Timestamp_End)
        VALUES('$User_Id','$date','Open','$new_time')";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

        if($result){
            $sql1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Story_Common ORDER BY Story_Id DESC";
            $res1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);
            if (sqlsrv_has_rows($res1) == true)
            {
                while ($row_sql1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res1, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH))
                {
                    $Story_Id = $row_sql1["Story_Id"];
                }
            }

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Story(Story_Id,Story_Content,B_Id)
            VALUES('$Story_Id',N'$Story_Content','$B_Id')";
            $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);

            if($result2){
                $response['success'] = 200;
                $response['message'] = "Insert in db success.";
            }
            else{
                $response['success'] = 0;
                $response['message'] = "Failed to insert db.";
            }
        }
        else{
            $response['success'] = 0;
            $response['message'] = "Failed to insert db.";
        }

    }
    else if($Type == 'Photo/Video'){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Story_Common(User_Id,Timestamp_Start,Status,Timestamp_End)
        VALUES('$User_Id','$date','Open','$new_time')";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

        if($result){

            if (empty($_FILES["Attachment"]["name"])) {
                $path = "NA";
            } 
            else {
                $Attachment=$_FILES["Attachment"]["name"];
                $temp=$_FILES["Attachment"]["tmp_name"];
                $tst= time();
                $url = "Post_Media/" . $tst . $Attachment;
                $path="http://kidsfb.kidsfb.com/ver1PHP/".$url;
                move_uploaded_file($temp,$url);
            }

            $sql1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Story_Common ORDER BY Story_Id DESC";
            $res1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);
            if (sqlsrv_has_rows($res1) == true)
            {
                while ($row_sql1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res1, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH))
                {
                    $Story_Id = $row_sql1["Story_Id"];
                }
            }

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Story_Media(Story_Id,Media_Att)
            VALUES('$Story_Id','$path')";
            $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);

            if($result2){
                $response['success'] = 200;
                $response['message'] = "Insert in db success.";
            }
            else{
                $response['success'] = 0;
                $response['message'] = "Failed to insert db.";
            }
        }
        else{
            $response['success'] = 0;
            $response['message'] = "Failed to insert db.";
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Tried increasing the buffer size to 2048 from 1024 still doesn't work on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

It is work to me very well so please try this one

//php file imageUpload.php

```
$encodedImage = $_POST['image'];

$encodedImage_Name = $_POST['img_name'];

$imageLocation = "Images/IMG_$encodedImage_Name.jpg";
$imagpath="Images/IMG_$encodedImage_Name.jpg";
$uploade_url= 'http://192.168.1.18/'.$imagpath;


echo "[\n";

if(file_put_contents($imageLocation, base64_decode($encodedImage))){



$myObj=new \stdClass();
$myObj->success = 'true';
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
}
  else{

$myObj=new \stdClass();
$myObj->success = 'false';
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;

 }

  echo "]\n";
```

//java file

```
static final   int  PICK_FROM_GALLERY=123;
Bitmap imageBitmap;
 boolean isSelected;
```

//to open the image from gallery

```
profile.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), 
     Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
                } else {
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } );
```

//open image set to Bitmap

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==PICK_FROM_GALLERY){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri path = data.getData();
            try {
                imageBitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),path);
                profile.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                Log.e("Image path",imageBitmap+"");
                isSelected=true;
               

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}



public void UploadImage(){
   if (isSelected == true) {

       ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,75, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imageInByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        //picked image covert to base64
        String encodedImage =  Base64.encodeToString(imageInByte,Base64.DEFAULT);



        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody reqestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType( MultipartBody.FORM )
                .addFormDataPart( "image",encodedImage )
                .addFormDataPart( "img_name","abc" )
                .build();



          Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("Upload Url in Server (exsample : http://192.168.1.18/imageUpload.php) " )
                .post( reqestBody )
                .build();



              client.newCall( request ).enqueue( new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                String JSON_STRING = myResponse;
                                JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray( JSON_STRING );
                                JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject( 0 );
                                String success = mJsonObject.getString( "success" );

                                Log.d( "Image Uploade", success );


                                if (success.equals( "true" )) {
                                    Toast.makeText( getActivity(), " Success! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                } else {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText( getActivity(), " failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e( "Image Uploade", e.toString() );
                                Toast.makeText( getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                            
                               
                            }
                        }
                    } );
                } else {
                  
                    Log.d( "Image Uploade", "Error" );
                }
            }
        } );




}else{

          Toast.makeText( getActivity(), " Please select a PostImage before submitting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

      }


       }
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply, but it seems that the issue persists on images taken from the camera. The images taken from the camera are converted into a bitmap, also converted into base64 string. But while uploading it still throws the error for some unknown reason.

Comment: I think you are using  AsyncTask .But their has some problem when its come to the android 10 ..  but you can follow the my steps and it works perfectly. if did you think my answer will help to your problem .can you give to feedbacks to my profile